# Is it possible to use both GET and POST in a single form?

Tags: php, forms, post, get

Assigning GET for some fields and assigning POST for other files in the same form. Is it possible?

Comment: Why you need this requirement ?

Comment: This was my last question asked in an interview.

Comment: If this were an interview question, perhaps it is there to spark discussion.  To see if the candidate has a solid grasp of the http methods and their relevance in form submission.  I can understand the need to have different methods applied across submission buttons - but not so for mixing methods across text input fields.

Answer (score 3):

if you have Specified data for get method you can use by this

```
<form method="POST" action="form.php?a=1&b=2&c=3">

    .........
    .........

</form>
```

And if you want PHP GET and POST simultaneously via single HTML form Read this documentation.
[This](https://www.intechgrity.com/using-php-get-and-post-simultaneously-via-single-html-form/#)

Comment: 'GET method' suggests to me the http request method being GET.  In your form example the method is POST, and as such the http request method will be POST upon submission.  The addition of query parameters (which should be encoded correctly), may populate Php's $_GET superglobal, but are not indicative of the http request method.

Answer (score 2):

HTML 5 lets you mix methods by using the formmethod attribute:

```
<form method='POST'>
    <button formmethod='GET' name='foo' value='qux' type='submit'>Get</button>
    <input type='hidden' name='bah' value='humbug'>
    <input type='submit' name='bar' value='Post'>
</form>
```

Which allows you to submit the same form via POST or GET for example.

However, having one text input being submitted under POST and another under GET at the same time is not doable.

A form will only be submitted under one http method at a time.  In Php you can check that via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.